# Redirect contact form to another page after submit

Tags: controllers, contact-us, default

How can I redirect the default Magento form to a separate thank you page on submission, rather than redirecting it to the contact form with the thank you message itself?

Here is my `Indexcontroller.php` code:

```
class Mage_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'contacts/email/recipient_email';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER     = 'contacts/email/sender_email_identity';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE   = 'contacts/email/email_template';
    const XML_PATH_ENABLED          = 'contacts/contacts/enabled';

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();

        if( !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED) ) {
            $this->norouteAction();
        }
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')
            ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );

        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                        return;
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my `form.phtml` code:

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php //echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
</div>
<div class="contact-main">
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('contact-address')->toHtml(); ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" class="scaffold-form">
<div class="page-title1">
    <h1><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></span></h1>
</div>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="tel" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Please add your Magento version, you want to redirect a contact form after submit to another page right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override this core controller file:

**app\code\core\Mage\Contacts\controllers\IndexController.php**

in this file you can see a function **postAction()**
under this function you can see below lines written

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

you can see  `*/*/` will redirect the customer to contact form url with this code after successfully submit the contact form.

you can replace these two line with below line like:

> $this->_redirect('frontname/controller/action'); 
> or 
>  
>   $this->_redirect('cms_page_identifier');

Comment: so i have to remove this line: Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('...........'));
$this->_redirect('*/*/');   with these line:    $this->_redirect('frontname/controller/action'); 
or $this->_redirect('cms_page_identifier');  but you see there is also a function like this :public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')
            ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') );
    } here you see a line :   ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post') ); what does this do?

Comment: still i am being redirected to the contact form page with the thank you message in it.

Comment: please check my codes given above and suggest me a solution.

Comment: indexAction() function will show contact form only.
Are you able to override controller file successfully? Use echo and exit on starting of postAction() and check if your overridden file is calling or not.